# Is it possible to render value of $scope.something inside script?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-treeview

I'm really new in **Web development**, So sorry if it's only a little misunderstanding and very miner things.

I'm trying to use this [bootstrap-treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview), and component will bind to this existing DOM element,

```
<div id="tree"></div>
```

With the basic usage like this,

```
function getTree() {
  // Some data
  return data;
}    
$('#tree').treeview({data: getTree()});
```

Now, I want to set `treeview` using `angularJS`, So that I tried
 setting `ng-model` to that `div` element and assigned `data` from the `$scope` object like `$scope.myData = myData;`. But it didn't work.

It will be fine if I could possibly mix up the same as given in the description of the library, and retrieve the value of `$scope` object
 inside `<script>` section like this

```
<script>
    var data = //how to Recieve $scope.myData here
    $('#tree').treeview({ data: getTree() });
</script>
```

Is it possible to get the value of `$scope.myData` inside `<script>`?
Or any kind of suggestions to accomplish my task, or even `duplication` will be greatly appreciated if there is something similar.

I am sorry because I'm really new in these `angularJS` and other stuffs like `Jquery`.

Comment: Question is, where is $scope.myData located?

Comment: you can wrap the treeview library in your own angular directive, but it is better and easier to find an Angular library that does the same thing, i.e. https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-treeview

Comment: @ImantsVolkovs It's inside one of the controller of angular as the variable tree of the link provided above.

Comment: @sdfacre thank you very much bro, I will try that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you want you should create an AngularJS directive and wrap the initiation of `bootstrap-treeview` inside it. Something like this:

```
myModule.directive('treeView', [function() {

        return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    myData: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                    var data = scope.myData;

                    $('#tree').treeview({data: data});
                }
        };
}]);
```

Then use it like this:

```
<div id="tree" tree-view my-data="myData"></div>
```

Comment: Thank u for your quick answer, But I'm still confused. Where should I put that data ? After the `myData : //here` ? And how to get it in the page ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna What does the getTree() do?

Comment: It is a function which returns data. There is complete explanation with example as well in the link above. I don't know jquery as well :(.

Comment: How about `treeview({data: data})`?

Comment: means ? where is it ?.. Will you give me some suggestions about how to do this task from angularjs. Suppose I have that data in my angular module and I want to pass that data to `<div id="tree"></div>`. What way will you prefer if you were supposed for this task. please Provide some hints, and I'll accept this answer. Will you please.

Comment: I found this really complex bro, I'm sure I cant resolve these as well if something happened in future. I've decided to use another [way](https://github.com/dump247/angular.tree) Thank you very much for your effort and precious time..

Comment: I'd take the time to fully understand javascript before attempting to work with AngularJS and jQuery. It will help you in the future.